# "Missing Operating System" GRUB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, grub, format

Okay ill keep it quick, I screwed up when formatting my harddrive so now I have this issue

"missing operating system GRUB" when trying to boot

And if I try to boot from a live CD or USB I just get "GRUB" and nothing else, I have my Boot menu in BIOS in the correct order and the CDs and USBs do work for other computers.

I cant fix my issue as I cant load up any OS, I dont care about anything thats on the computer I basically just want it wiped so I can install a new linux distro on it.

How would I go about fixing this? Sorry about long post

Computer I'm using is an eMachine em350 netbook

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are not supposed to worry about any data in your computer, then things are easy. format the whole disc using any third party software like partition magic.and then do a installation of operating system. bootable disk like hiren's boot disk can also be used.

Comment: Im unable to boot from anything

Comment: you tried hiren boot disk.is it loading windows or linux. are you able too the HDD in hiren disk?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot from any Linux LiveCD/USB and reformat your drive. Double-check that you're *actually* booting from the media and not from your hard drive. Doing it properly shouldn't cause the broken Grub's prompt/menu to pop up.

You can also try Windows setup media to see if that works.

If all else fails you might have to remove the drive and connect it to another machine to format it, although this shouldn't really be required.

Comment: Problem is I cant boot from any of that, and I definetly am doing it properly as Ive done it countless times before :(

Comment: I gave you the alternative solutions that you can try.

Comment: Cant boot from windows either still same issue, also don't really want to dismantle my netbook as I'm not comfortable with my skills. No other way to do this software wise? Thanks for all the help

Comment: Given you're doing everything correctly, I'm still at a loss to understand why it's no longer able to boot from a CD or USB. Other than this I don't know any way to format the drive.